# Getting a different kind of token for google recapthca v3

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, grecaptcha

On my backend, I noticed that I am receiving google ReCaptcha v3 tokens like this, Please help me to understand that

> HFM2dyIB5URz10GFdHHU1WHAEJZDAIGCZ2cCciUR4GXwcuT2cBMFwWe21tFjxbOENuIhgXWkgaVxQDXzBDXj0waWF-JRUPNhoZHgd0IyF9BTMjFk8tHm1ROjpTSEFcBAhaHgslB0p0MiBpOXgAT2V6JF4SNXcTJVRNZV1LbFlvTGcyE14WQWBfHUdaOnAfaFMlLzomVgwEKBsrRD5WZlNbB2h0BiZVHXdbZVBDFnJ6GHJQNycySSo3RQ
>
> HFdGxiZxVEADZkX1xXWkZGWwoZIzsYXy1mNywyFhUWGAw-CGwRd1cGPGZ9UTdLf0h-ZRMHHUMKEB8TGDtTGTYgLmpuYh4fcREJWQxkZCptQjgzUUQ9WWZBfTFDD0pMQwNKWQA1QEFkdSt5fnMQCG5qY1UCcnwDYl9dIlZbK1J_C2wiVFUGBmtPWkxKfXsPL1g1aDE2EQcUbxA7AzVGIVhLQGNkQS1FWnxLIltTUXlqX3lAcCwiDiEnAg
>
> HFN2FxJBhXQzt3HFFEGUtVGAcKYDYLHCB1dCEhVRgFWwEtS2ECNFoVf2tuEjpYPEVtJh4UXk4ZUxIAWzZAWjszbWd9IRMMMhwaGgF3Jyd-ATUgEkkuGmtSPjxQTEdfAA5ZGg0mA0x3NiZqPX4DS2N5IFgRMXEQIVJOYVtIaF9sSGExF1gVRWZcGUFZPnYcbFUmKzwlUgoHLB0oQDhVYlVYA253AiBWGXFYYVZAEnR5HHRTMyExTSw0QQQ

Comment: So what's your question? Why do you think the token should always be the same?

Comment: @JonasWilms Regular we get a token like this whcih starts with 03 - 03AGdBq27qVWKNdu1s6heQIiNFqqaDV2-h9-k24LcPfAD8vi8-M73sFXtPxC1_iPUyUPw-bHPj7ra3l0GxEb8j4hGgfQK7Q1RjpxP7jq-ps0QOKD24GU3LljroK35nH-apUVt7GIAKyGHymzmGqgFnBeUIoT2xD4AXBk-NEXFE9WlANI8vh3DZ0QKgTYc8-0dDWNGfhzm5KG0RVSvXryallXcDrJ3od1lXDZKeyyuL68Vv6YxmbhKtXgtiqdnZESiGIYJq0XTqQaB_uXBOnctUbRTD8x-SulJf7Q0ZdaUzg2q6ksxjLEO4RHCbs4zB0ic4wgwrEBIJhGnkCzMmzzsQkb_P5U9PdG9PsjDwL_DgKersmXVcgLRFzARiA8w5QVc3S0H4HzlW-X4cuwDwAV5tMoctmrU7gE5BWc1FZhTWZpW3YmmibydOtktdrPK4a_yryNpPNj-F-LD-PO6PYf38Ks1hNcY-zqhhcDht3k0pf7iV24SkOBaMZKtkFhKPWqht48yviAQ32_CW